# Background image cover size with rollover responsible: is it possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this kind of challenge:
image on backgound of body, backgound-size, cover to fit whole screen. and on the background image are some elements(building). So I want to hover over the building and they change collor or add shadow etc. the problem is on screen resize, when I'm resizing the screen I can't find a formula that will move an overlay div to fit the building in the background.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>website</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/fixes.js"></script>

<!--[if lt IE 9]>                
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
</head>

<body class="home">
    <div class="map">       
        <div class="building1"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
.home{
  background:url(../img/homeBg1200.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function fixes() {
        var windowW = window.innerWidth,
            windowH = window.innerHeight;

        if(windowW > 1199) {
            var proportionH,
                proportionW,
                indexTop,
                indexLeft,
                top1,
                left1,
                width1,
                height1;



                //indexTop = (proportionH-800)/3;

                if((windowW / windowH) < 1.5) {
                    proportionW = (windowH * 1200/800);
                    proportionH = (proportionW * 800/1200);
                    indexLeft = (proportionW - 1200)*0.001;
                    indexTop = (proportionH - 800)*0.001;
                    top1 = proportionH*0.178-indexTop;
                    left1 = proportionW*0.476-indexLeft;
                    width1 = (proportionW )*0.084;
                    height1 = (proportionH)*0.482;
                } else {
                    proportionH = (windowW * 800/1200);
                    proportionW = (proportionH * 1200/800);
                    indexLeft = (proportionW - 1200)*0.001;
                    indexTop = (proportionH - 800)/2;
                    top1 = proportionH*0.178-indexTop;
                    left1 = proportionW*0.476+indexLeft;
                    width1 = (proportionW )*0.084;
                    height1 = (proportionH)*0.482;
                }

            $('.building1').css({
                'top': top1,
                'left': left1,
                'width':width1,
                'height':height1
            }); 

        }
    }

    fixes();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        fixes();
    });
});
```

it is possible to achieve this?

Thank you

ps: just replicated the code here: http://hardware-trade.com/site/

Comment: any comment will be very useful at this moment, even if it is possible to achieve this or not. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be fixed without javascript. You should use media queries in css.